# How to differentiate between MacRoman and Windows-1251 encodings in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, csv, import-from-excel

I'm pulling my hairs for a few days now. I've googled and stackoverflowed a lot without success.

I'm importing some data from a csv file. This CSV file is generated in Excel either on Windows or Mac, which gives 2 different encodings "Windows-1251" and "MacRoman". Both are variants from ISO-8859-1 and mb_detect_encoding dos not help : it always detect the first encoding I put in the list.

For example :

```
mb_detect_encoding($buffer, 'macroman, windows-1251, UTF-8');
```

Will give "macroman".

With the same string, trying :

```
mb_detect_encoding($buffer, 'windows-1251, macroman, UTF-8');
```

will give "window-1251".

So how can you properly make the difference ? I need to convert my input string (the csv file content) to utf-8 to insert into the DB.

Maybe I'm missing something? How do you guys usually manage to parse csv files, and save data properly in DB (utf8).

Thanks for any clue!

Comment: Where from you taking this csv file? If from site - maybe charset declared in headers? If uploaded manually - maybe it's possible to change encoding of file before uploading?

Comment: does your data actually contain anything that's not in plain ascii (character codes above 0x7F), or do you actually have ISO-8859-1 chars in one, and Cyrillic in the other?

Comment: I wouldn't trust mb_detect_encoding() and allow the user to choose the source of data. Depending on what's inside the data file, mb_detect_encoding() might or might not produce be good results.

Comment: Windows version of the file was sent to me by email, when I open it in Textmate, it tells me it is ISO-8859-1. If I open my own version, generated on a Mac, it tells me MacRoman. So far so good. Data contains mainly ISO-8859-15 letters (french letters such éèêàùôç...). Then I upload the file on my webapp and try to convert to utf8. utf8_encode works for the windows version of the file, and iconv('MacRoman', 'UTF-8', $fileContent) works for the Mac version. Thanks for your comments so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to make sure this is handled properly is to define a process for saving the csv file in the first place. Then you just have to utf8_encode what's coming in and it'll go fine...

Comment: a process for saving the csv file ? Do you mean when creating it, or when saving it on the web server file system? For the former, I cannot expect my client to do it properly, but I could save my own file in latin1, how do you do that from Excel? (I have Excel Mac 2008)

Comment: I mean that the person creating the file on a mac should always "save as windows csv file" or something similar to ensure the encoding is consistent.

Comment: It's been a long time I didn't play around with this, but we had csv imports to db working fine without (unreliable) mb_detect_encoding(), using only fgetcsv() and utf8_encode().

Comment: Bascially, what I'm saying is that there is no good automated way to find out what encoding we are confronted to, so we need to tell the user "make sure you output this kind of encoding, or all hell will break loose" ;)

Comment: thanks, I guess this is the most pragmatic solution. You know how "unreliable" it can be when you ask your client "make sure ..." but hey, I have no other choice ;)